# Convert ODE to polar coordinates.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

$$k \frac{d}{dx}[A(x)\frac{dT(x)}{dx}] - hP(x)[T(x) - T] = 0 $$

What I had in mind was:
$$x = rcosϴ,  r = \frac{x}{cosϴ} , \frac{dr}{dx} = \frac{1}{cosϴ} $$
$$\frac{dA(x)}{dx} = \frac{dA(r)}{dx}\frac{dr}{dx} = \frac{1}{cosϴ}\frac{dA(r)}{dr}$$
$$\frac{dT(x)}{dx} = \frac{dT(r)}{dx}\frac{dr}{dx} = \frac{1}{cosϴ}\frac{dT(r)}{dr}$$
$$\frac{d²T(x)}{dx²} = \frac{d}{dr}[\frac{dT(r)}{dr}\frac{1}{cosϴ}]\frac{dr}{dx} = \frac{1}{cosϴ}\frac{d²T(r)}{dr²}$$
$$\frac{k}{cos²ϴ}\frac{d}{dr}[A(r)\frac{dT(r)}{dr}] - hP(r)[T(r) - T] = 0 $$
but I'm getting the sensation that this is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Polar coordinates are two-dimensional; your problem has just one spatial variable, so that's clearly not the way to go. However, the your ODE is second order, so it can be written as a two-dimensional system of first order ODEs:
\begin{align}
 A(x)\frac{\text{d} T}{\text{d} x} &= S(x),\\
 k \frac{\text{d} S}{\text{d} x} &= h P(x) \left(T(x)-T\right).
\end{align}
You can now try to convert $(T,S)$ to polar coordinates, i.e. write
\begin{align}
 T(x) &= r(x)\,\cos[ \theta(x)],\\
 S(x) &= r(x)\,\sin[ \theta(x)],
\end{align}
and substitute this in the system to get equations for $\frac{\text{d} r}{\text{d} x}$ and $\frac{\text{d} \theta}{\text{d} x}$. However, as long as $P(x)$ is unknown, this is of limited value.

Comment: This is from a fin problem where the changes in temperature in the y and z direction can be disregarded so I can look for T(x) instead of T(x,y,z), so I kind of tried to apply the same logic in polar coordinates as T will change predominantly in r. x = rcosθ, will fix that on OP.

I don't want to sound rude but are you sure this: T(x)=r(x)cos[θ(x)],  S(x)=r(x)sin[θ(x)], is correct? I don't see how derivating T(x) and multiplying it by A(x) will give me S(x) and the temperature being described only with r and θ doesn't look right.

Comment: A(x) is the cross section area of the fin and P(x) the perimeter, so both are known.

Comment: I suggest you add all of this to your question, as it is relevant to the method of approach. What is 'correct' highly depends on the background of the problem, which is missing at the moment. The reformulation of your second order ODE as a two-dimensional system of first order ODEs is exact, btw, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#System_of_ODEs .